# DatagramChannel, Selector and thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a simple java application that has several `UDP connections` (several `DatagramChannel`).
I'm using selector and register each of the channels to `OP_READ`.

Each `isReadable` key (for each channel) will be handled by a separate thread. 
I have a thread pool (`ExecutorService`) which will limit the number of threads (number of threads which handle the reading from the channel).

I have another thread which dispatch the selected keys (readable keys).

My approach fails because the next time I select keys, some keys are returned again, because the `thread pool` has not finished working on them yet.

Do you have any suggestions ?

here the main section from my code (I gave here the main logic...):

public class CConnectionManager extends Thread {

private ExecutorService m_TxExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

private void waitForReadyChannels()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int readyChannels = 0;
        try {
                readyChannels = m_selector.select(10000);
                if (0 < readyChannels)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                System.out.print("\nError while waiting for ready channels");
        }
    }
}

private void handleReadConnection (CConnection connection)
{

```
Thread cRxThread = connection.getRxTread();     
if (false == cRxThread.isAlive())
{
    CRxTask cRxTask = connection.getRxTask();
    m_RxExecutor.execute(cRxTask);  
}
```

}

public void run() {

```
     // go over the selector
     while (true) {

                waitForReadyChannels(); 
                Set<SelectionKey> keys = m_selector.selectedKeys();                     
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = keys.iterator();                   

                while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                    SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                    keyIterator.remove();                                                               
                    CConnection connection = (CConnection) key.attachment();

                    if (key.isReadable()) {                     
                        handleReadConnection(connection);                           
                    }                       
                }

     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Your problem is probably as simple as not removing ready keys from the selected-key set as they are processed, but the real question here is why? If you're prepared to have separate threads, which BTW you don't need in NIO, why use NIO at all?

Comment: I want to use NIO beacuse the use of the selector. 
moreover, for example, I have 20 different UDP channels and 5 threads to handle all those 20 channes incomming data. so why cant I do so ?

Comment: any one can help , pls ?